# Color this map using only 4 colors (easy)

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science

According to graph theory, in order to color any map so that 2 touching regions don't have the same color, 4 distinct colors are enough.

Can somebody color the following map?

[image]

Comment: I was just trying a different puzzle. You people are pretty quick with downvotes :D

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the answer:

> [image]

This was pretty easy though.

Answer (score 8):

> 7 is surrounded by 3 squares that all touch, so they are each one of the four colours.

Let us mark them as

> 7: Red, 6: Blue: 2: Green, 1: Black

Then

> 1,2, and 6 all border 3, so 3 is Red. 1,3,6 all border 8, so 8 is Green. 4 is then Blue, and 5 is Red. 6,3,8 border 9, so 9 is Black.

Final Colours:

> Red: 3,5,7; Blue: 4,6; Green: 2,8; Black: 1,9